# Piping Mesh Data back into original

Tags: animation-nodes

Just wondering about Blender AN workflow. Normally I have original mesh and do something and output as NEW mesh.

Wondering, if I actually plugging in whatever process back to original mesh, is this actually possible?

Say, perhaps I am pushing the vector of Suzanne head... the output currently is the NEW Target object.

Is there a correct way to do this?

[image]

Comment: If I plugged in the processed data into original mesh, it flies away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use a source and a target mesh object. Unfortunately it is not possible (well it is, but not useful in most cases) to use the source object as target.

The reason is that the original mesh data is lost when you overwrite the source. There is no way to get it back.

Comment: Aha... thanks for that information. I got it working just like "Modifier", in the way for beginner user it is good idea to see "original" and "result" as separate.

For what I am trying to do now, it is just to modify the "mesh data", and I could pipe back into the original "object" without issue. As long I did not accidentally making infinite loop and causing the object to fly away.

I use Object Instancer.

Original Object >> Object Instancer (make 1 copy of Mesh Data)
Do something to the Instance Mesh Data.
Just the mesh data I could just pass output into >> Original Object.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was something like this:

[image]

Perhaps not for all kind of situation, but this does something like Modifier.

Can be more elegant.

I don't know maybe either teach me to make Template, or perhaps some what Nodify the whole loop thing over itself that does this maybe :)

But my future wishlist is probably something with Color, but beforehand if you can make Sverchok bridge node it would be awesome!